# How to generate a fixed "pseudo-random" list of doubles in a certain range the same every time?

Tags: c#, math, random

For testing purposes, I require a fixed list of doubles of around 10000 values (no precise limit on list size is strictly necessary) in the approximate range -100 to 1000. This list has to be suitably "random", with no noticeable increment/multiplicative difference between values. However this fixed list also has to be the exact same every time I run my code.

How can I create such a list without some crazy amount of manual labour?

---

Obviously if the list didn't have to be the same every time it would be much easier, and I could simply use the `Random` library. Were that the case even a looping `yield return;` with a variable increment having a mean increase like `randonNum.Next(-50, 100)` would probably be suitable, but evidently an implementation like this would change every time I ran my code.

Comment: Have you seen [the seeded constructor of `Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use *seed* when creating random values generator:

```
Random gen = new Random(1234); // or other integer seed

int size = 10000;

List<Double> result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, size)
  .Select(_ => gen.NextDouble() * 1100.0 - 100.0) // [-100..1000] range
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the same numbers using the `Random`-[constructor with a seed-value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ctssatww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g:

```
var r = new Random(0);
```

Now you can use `r.NextInt` on it and should get the same numbers again and again.

Omitting the seed will lead to a default-seed of the current system-time which is guaranteed to be unique and therefor will lead to different results. Providing a constant one will create equal sequences all the time.